# Spring Reactive : convert Flux<Wrapper<X>> to Flux<X>

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, reactor

I have the endpoint : `/upstreams`

It will return Json in format:

```
{
  "next" : "String",
  "data" : [
    {
       "id" : "String",
       "name" : "String"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have several endpoints like this, so I create a wrapper class

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ResponseWrapper<T> {

    private List<T> data;

    private String next;

}
```

For the `/upstream` response above, the Data Type is `Upstream`

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Upstream extends Node {

    private String id;

    private String name;

}
```

Now I have a service that must return `Flux<Stream>` (or `List<Stream>`?), so I create this kind of method

```
@Override
public Flux<Stream> getAllNodes() {
    var endpoint = "/upstream";

    var response = webClient.get().uri(endpoint).retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<ResponseWrapper<Upstream>>() {
            });

    return ???;
}
```

How Can I convert the `ResponseWrapper<Upstream>` so it returns `Flux<Stream>` or `List<Stream>`?

I'm guessing `.flatMap()` or `map()`, but what is the correct usage?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

I believe your `var response` is a `Mono<ResponseWrapper<Upstream>>`, so something like this:

```
return response.flatMapMany(pesponseWrapper -> Flux.fromIterable(pesponseWrapper.getData()));
```